# Выбрать новости по по максимальной дате

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT news_id, title, description, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS readableDate
FROM re_news 
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = MAX(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)))
```

Есть SQL запрос нужно выбрать новости с самым большим годом, например все новости за последний год вот sql
Но такой запрос работает

```
SELECT news_id, title, description, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS readableDate
FROM re_news 
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2018
```

Comment: Выберите максимальный год в подзапросе.

Comment: делал все так же

Comment: *делал все так же* Значит, неправильно делал. `WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))) FROM re_news)`

Comment: @Akina, по-моему здесь можно обойтись одним «YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))» в подзапросе - сформировать дату (01.01.год) и выбирать всё начиная с этой даты - это позволит избежать второго FTS (Full Table Scan), если «date” индексирован

Comment: @MaxU Если присутствует индекс по дате - это будет не FTS, а index scan. А насчёт сборки даты начала года - согласен. Спасибо за поправку. И тогда уж, с учётом формата хранения, ещё и преобразовать полученную дату в UNIX_TIMESTAMP, чтобы вообще не иметь функции и использовать индекс при отборе в полном объёме.

Comment: @Akina, по-моему стОит ваш последний комментарий оформить как ответ ;)

Comment: @MaxU Не буду. Причём по странной на первый взгляд причине. Если оформлять ответом - надо дать готовое решение в учётом всего обсуждённого. Но имхо автор может это сделать самостоятельно, и это будет ему гораздо полезнее. А если он потом ещё опубликует своё решение как ответ, да ещё сопроводит сравнением скоростей - вот тогда и правда от наличия ответа будет польза.